# VBA IE automation Invisibility

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am trying to automate a webpage and  I only have one problem , that I made the IE object invisible and silent so users will not be able to see the web page

but suddenly the web page appears when the Save As notification bar shows up , I know how to handle the SaveAs dialouge using UIAutomation  but the problem is that the page always appears when the saveAs dialouge shows , is there any command I can use to make the page always invisible even when the page has notifications?

Comment: Hi, probably not. Which notification is it for? a download or to save the web page? Both invoke user acceptance prompts.

Comment: Hi, Rob it's a prompt for a file to be downloaded(open/save as prompt) , I already used "IUIAutomationInvokePattern" command  to automate this prompt but I can't make the page invisible while VBA is dealing with it ,
Is there any workaround like keeping the page in the background ?

Comment: You can move IE window outside of the screen using `moveTo`, then the only issue is that it will be still visible on the taskbar. Try to use XHR instead of IE automation.

Comment: thanks  omegastripes for your comment , I tried XHR but it didn't go smooth  can you pls tell me how to use "moveto" I have no problem if IE is visible on taskbar